# The Async pipe doesn't receive a value until I subscribe to the observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've faced with a wierd case, when the async pipe doesn't work properly until I subscribe to the observable. Sources:

View of the component:

```
<div *ngIf="loading$ | async" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <span class="spinner">Loading...</span>
</div>

<h1>{{data$ | async}}</h1>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: './tm-fake',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './fake.component.html'
})
export class FakeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private _fs: FakeService
  ) {}

  loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  data$ = this._fs.data$.pipe(indicateUntilNULL(this.loading$));

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._fs.requestData();

    //this.data$.subscribe(e => {});
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class FakeService {
  requestData(): void {
    timer(2000).pipe(map(e => "data")).subscribe(e => this._data.next(e));
  }

  private readonly _data = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  readonly data$ = this._data.asObservable();
}
```

Operator:

```
export function indicateUntilNULL<T>(indicator: BehaviorSubject<boolean>): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
  return source => source.pipe(
    tap(e => indicator.next(!e))
  );
}
```

I see the `data` after 2 sec delay as excpected, but I didn't see a spinner during this delay. But if I uncomment the line `this.data$.subscribe(e => {});` it starts to work fine. And I can't find the reason. Any ideas?

NB: `loading$` emits correct values even this line is commented.

**SOLUTION**

Many thanks to @theMayer and his helpful advice. I just want to add the [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/), where the problem is explained in details. And according this article the most elegant solution is a `delay(0)` operator:

```
export function indicateUntilNULL<T>(indicator: BehaviorSubject<boolean>): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
  return source => source.pipe(
    delay(0),
    tap(e => indicator.next(!e))
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you initializing with Null? That is not how it is supposed to be used

Comment: Can you try just printing `{{ loading$ | async }}`? Because what you have should work even with `onPush`.

Comment: @theMayer Because I don't have data right after page loaded. it should be requested from API. I replaced it with a timer for simplicity

Comment: @martin  the same - I replaced a spinner with `<h1>{{loading$ | async}}</h1>` and it shows false all the time without subscription and works as expected with subscription - first it shows `true`, and then - after delay `false`.

Comment: A boolean cannot logically be anything other than true or false. I would recommend initializing it with a value.

Comment: @theMayer yes, look at the sources - the `loading$` is initialized with `false` actually: `loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);`
`data$` is initialized with null, and that's ok

Comment: Can you be clearer on the expected behavior? As far as I can tell, your code is set up to do exactly what you say it does, but I'm not sure what it's not doing that you'd like it to do.

Comment: @theMayer initial `data$` value is null, and the requested value appears after 2 sec. During this delay `loading$` has to be true (for displaying `Loading...` spinner), but it hasn't. And it starts working as excpected only when I uncomment this line: `this.data$.subscribe(e => {});`. And I don't understand why...

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out what is not happening. The question is whether this is a defect in Angular or a misuse of `async` pipe. I suspect the value is being updated in the middle of change detection, which would mean another change detection cycle would need to pick it up, but nothing exists to trigger it.

Comment: Would you be able to set up a stackblitz so I can play with this a bit?

Comment: @theMayer I have to go away right now. I will do it in couple of hours. I will nofity you. Thanks )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after reviewing your code, I think I understand the question. You are not seeing the updated value of `true` emitted via the `loading$` observable picked up in the DOM.

Here is what your code says will happen:

1. The objects will be constructed, and the behavior subject `_data` will be initialized with a null value.
2. The Angular template will render in and go through change detection. It will pick up `false` for the `loading` value and `null` for `data`. The loading spinner will not spin.
3. Later in the change detection cycle, the `async` pipe will trigger the `true` value to be emitted by `loading`. This happens synchronously; since change detection was set to `OnPush`, I suspect this change is going to be missed because there is already a change detection cycle in progress when the value was set (normally, this might be caught by the regular change detection strategy and raised as an error).
4. Then your `data` emits after the two second delay.

Note that, when using regular change detection, this sort of a situation will result in a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. The correct approach is to ensure the internal consistency of your component *prior to* the change detection cycle rather than do things during change detection which trigger further changes.

The quick answer is to set your "loading" value to true initially, since the code will always try to load data when it initializes.

Comment: I'm totally frustrated. I've created project with exact the same code on the stackblitz and it works fine. But locally it doesn't. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wutfat

Comment: By the way: changing initial value to `true` works. Using the default change strategy doesn't fix the problem

Comment: The default change strategy would only work if you have no parent components using the push strategy.  It works on Stackblitz because you are not overriding the change detection strategy there.

Comment: Have a look at the console on your Stackblitz. You'll see `ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.`

Comment: it looks like the problem is described in the following article: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: it looks like I fixed it. Thanks ) I just added `delay(0)` operator into a pipe of `indicator` operator.

Answer (score -2):

You need `share()` Here's my working example:

```
public $route!: Observable<{}>;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.$route = this.route.data.pipe(share());
}
```

Then in the view

```
<ng-container *ngIf="$route | async as route; else loading">
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: How in any way does this address the original question?

Comment: I just believe that answers should at least make an attempt to address the original question. This one does not. Not only is no explanation provided, but it doesn't even try to use the original code from the question.